# Android SQLite возвращает пустое значение

Tags: android, sqlite

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с SQLite.

DatabaseHelper.java

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final String LOG = "###MY_DB_LOG###";

    public static final String TABLE = "PROJNAMES";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "projname";
    public static final String COLUMN_INFO = "info";

    private static final String DB_NAME = "PROJECTSBASE.db"; //имя базы
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1; //версия базы

    private String CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " ("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_INFO + " TEXT" + ");";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
         }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CreateTable);

        ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
        c.put(COLUMN_NAME, "Star Wars");
        c.put(COLUMN_INFO, "Luke Skywalker");
        db.insert(TABLE, null, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

Кусок кода из MainActivity

```
 DatabaseHelper DatabaseHelperMain = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            try {
                SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseHelperMain.getReadableDatabase();

                /*
                Создаем курсор для получения таблицы PROJECTSNAME столбцов NAME и MAIN_INFO тех записей,
                у которых значение _id равно ....
                 */
                Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelperMain.TABLE, null, null,null,null,null,null);

                if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

                    nameText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelperMain.COLUMN_NAME));

                }

                newnameP = nameText;
                mainStorage.addItem(newnameP);

                Log.i(LOG,  newnameP + " !!!");

                cursor.close();
                db.close();

            }   catch (SQLException e) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"Database unvaliable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
```

При этом лог Log.i(LOG,  newnameP + " !!!"); показывает **null !!!**. Подскажите, с чем может быть ошибка? Курение доков не помогает.

Заранее спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Скорее всего в БД нет ни одной записи. `cursor.getCount()` - подскажет сколько существует записей в таблице. И важно помнить, что вашем случае создание таблицы и заполнение её происходит после установки приложения и первом обращении к БД. Если до этого вы уже удаляли данные в таблице - то они создадутся только после удаления приложения или очистки данных приложения через настройки.

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался. Перезапустил на эмуляторе, плюс добавил цикл do - while для cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашей БД нет ни одной записи. Поэтому вы получаете null как результат.

Метод `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` срабатывает только при первом обращении приложения к классу. Было бы не логично, каждый раз при запуске приложения создавать пустые таблицы и вносить данные по умолчанию.

Если БД менялась, например добавились таблицы, нужно увеличивать значение `DB_VERSION`, например на 1. И в методе `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)` выполнять операции по обновлению уже установленной БД приложения.

Дам рекомендации касательно работы с БД. (Любые константы и классы должны начинаться с Заглавной буквы, а переменные и методы со строчной, нарушение не является ошибкой, но эти правила упростят процесс понимания кода.)

```
DatabaseHelper dbHelperMain = new DatabaseHelper(this); // если обращение к БД происходит только в одном методе, тогда можно оставить, в противном случае - перенести код в onCreate активити.
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelperMain.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(dbHelperMain.TABLE, null, null,null,null,null,null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
//всю работу с переменными, которым присваивается значение из БД, нужно делать в этом условии.
nameText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelperMain.COLUMN_NAME));
newnameP = nameText;
mainStorage.addItem(newnameP);
}
else{
//В БД не оказалась записей, здесь можно либо вызвать метод, который добавит нужные данные, либо выведет сообщение, что записей в базе нет.
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"По запросу не нашлось ни одной записи", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
Log.i(LOG,  newnameP + " !!!"); //для отладки лучше оставлять вне условий
cursor.close(); // да нужно освободить память после работы с курсором.
//db.close(); // не нужно закрывать соединение, это может привести к ошибкам.
//Особенно если другой метод всё еще работает с БД, или пытается открыть соединение.
//обычно соединение само закрывается (поправьте если ошибаюсь)
```

Comment: Спасибо за правки, исправлю и учту в будущем.